# Solve network issue LP-problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, problem-solving, programming, network

The notation is as follows. Let the network (N, A) be an oriented graph consisting of a number of nodes and edges with a given direction, indexed by $n∈ N = {1, ..., N}$ and $(n,m)∈ A ⊆ {(n,m) :n,m∈ N,n≠m}$}. A node corresponds to a location in the network and an edge to a transmission connection (ie a cable) between two nodes. Each node has a given net supply such that $d_n> 0$ (measured in MWh) if the node offers more than it demands, $d_n <0$ if inverse and $d_n = 0$ if the node is merely for transit. Each edge (n, m) is connected to a transmission cost $c_{nm}$ (DKK(danish money) / MWh). The net supply and costs are parameters, whereas the transmission on the edges is represented by decision variables. The transmission on edge (n, m) is denoted as $l_{nm}$ (MWh).
I have to solve the following instance of the network issue:

[image]

The graph indicates data for the network problem. The number on the edge (n, m) indicates costs, $c_{nm}$, and the number at the node indicates supply or demand, $d_n$ ($d_n$> 0 indicates supply and $d_n$ <0 indicates demand). A stretchy tree is marked with bold edges.

I think I then get the LP-problem:
$$Min\\\ 3x_{ab}+2x_{ad}+4x_{bc}+4x_{be}+x_{ca}+2x_{cd}+7x_{ce}+5x_{de}+3x_{ea}$$
$$ubb \\\ x_{ca}+x_{ea}-x_{ab}-x_{ad}= 2$$
$$ x_{ab}-x_{bc}-x_{be}= -8$$
$$ x_{bc}-x_{ca}-x_{cd}-x_{ce}= 5$$
$$ x_{ad}+x_{cd}-x_{de}=-6$$
$$ x_{be}+x_{ce}+x_{de}-x_{ea}=7$$

We find $Ax=-b$

A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix} -b=\begin{pmatrix}
-2\\
8\\
-5\\
6\\
-7\\
\end{pmatrix}

with rows a,b,c,d,e and columns (a,b),(a,d),(b,c),(b,e),(c,a),(c,d),(c,e),(d,e),(e,a).
What to do now? Can someone help me with the rest?
can be solved by future substitution?

Comment: What is the goal of this problem? And what is the meaning of the numbers at the nodes?

Comment: Now I have added some more about the problem.
There is an invisible arrow to itself at the numbers at the nodes

Comment: $x$ has to be nonnegative, so you cannot just solve it by substitution. You need an algorithm such as the simplex method. There are free online solvers such as the one at linprog.com or simplexme.com, or free offline solvers such as COIN-OR Clp.

Comment: Can you please help me to find a solution using this? What solution do you got?