# Find LP-problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, programming

The notation is as follows. Let the network (N, A) be an oriented graph consisting of a number of nodes and edges with a given direction, indexed by $n∈ N = {1, ..., N}$ and $(n,m)∈ A \subset {(n,m) :n,m∈ N,n≠m}$}. A node corresponds to a location in the network and an edge to a transmission connection (i.e. a cable) between two nodes. Each node has a given net supply such that $d_n> 0$ (measured in MWh) if the node offers more than it demands, $d_n <0$ if inverse and $d_n = 0$ if the node is merely for transit. Each edge (n, m) is connected to a transmission cost $c_{nm}$ (DKK(danish money) / MWh). The net supply and costs are parameters, whereas the transmission on the edges is represented by decision variables. The transmission on edge (n, m) is denoted as $l_{nm}$ (MWh).

[image]
The graph indicates data for the network problem. The number on the edge (n, m) indicates costs, $c_{nm}$, and the number at the node indicates supply or demand, $d_n$ ($d_n$> 0 indicates supply and $d_n$ <0 indicates demand). A stretchy tree is marked with bold edges.

Assume there are capacity constraints on transmission connections. Let $l^{max}_{nm}$ denote the capacity on edge (n, m) (in MW).

I have to write the general network problem with capacity constraints as a linear programming problem (LP-problem), but how can I do that?

Comment: Why ask again with less demonstration of your effort? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781298/solve-network-issue-lp-problem

Comment: Here, you usually also have edge costs, i.e. "the money you pay for transmitting" (whereas your "costs" are merely something like a currency exchange factor). Hint: The vector that you are optimizing corresponds to the flow. You are minimizing the sum of flow values times the costs (that I just described), so this is a linear objective. Then you have three kinds of constraints as you described: Flows must be nonnegative, at most the capacity, and the flow excess is specified in each vertex (note that ingoing edges will have additional multiplicative factors because of the "exchange concept").

Comment: Thank you a lot